# How do I draw the bounding rectangle of a Picture in gloss?

Tags: haskell, gloss

Is there a function in gloss that, given a Picture returns the width, height and coordinates of the smallest rectangle that encloses the Picture? If not, is it possible to write one?

Comment: I think, in the module `Graphics.Gloss.Game` there is a `boundingBox` functions which is what you need

Comment: There does not seem to be any module called Graphics.Gloss.Game - could you provide a link to the documentation for the boundingBox function?

Comment: oh! apparently is a plug-in package around gloss called `gloss-game`. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss-game-0.3.3.0/docs/Graphics-Gloss-Game.html. By the way, the `boundingBox` function seems to be incomplete.